# how to forcefully change the browser mode in IE9 to IE9 compatibility mode for a particular page in a .net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to forcefully change the *browser mode* in **IE9 to 
IE9 compatibility mode** for a particular page in a .net application ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
     <clear />
      <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9" />
   </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
```

or

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Comment: ive tried the meta tag solution but it doesnt seem to work.